# How to use list comprehension to create list from a "diagonal" range in a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension

Ultimately, I would like to use reduce and find a product. I know how to perform this problem using for loops, but I understand list comprehensions are faster and generally more "pythonic" so I'm trying my hardest to understand how to do my desired movement inside of a list comprehension.

So here's an example:

```
grid = [[a, b, c, d]
        [e, f, g, h]
        [i, j, k, l]
        [m, n, o, p]
        [q, r, s, t]]  # All the sublists are integer lists.
```

So ultimately what I'd like to do is `reduce()` *some* elements of these sublists, choosing them in a diagonal fashion. So let's say for this example I want to go through a down-right diagonal of length 3. If I'm starting at [0][0], my list comprehension would work through `[a, f, k]`. Here's some code I have tried so far:

```
diag_len = 3
i = 0
j = 0
# Purposely omitting the reduce() part of this next line
desired_list = grid[i:i + diag_len][j:j + diag_len]
```

As is, the code above takes the entire sublists of indices 0, 1, and 2 in `grid` rather than just the three elements in the desired diagonal. A `for` equivalent for what I want, my current solution, looks like this:

```
for z in range(diag_len):
    desired_list.append(num_grid[i + z][j + z])
    desired_product *= desired_list[z]
```

I looked at similarly labeled questions on SO but could not find anyone moving across two indices at once using list comprehension, apologies if I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to create a list of items along any diagonal in your matrix with input for row and column indices along with the length of the diagonal. And then use `reduce()` to get the product of the integers in the resulting list.

For example (you may want to bulletproof the function a bit more to prevent errors resulting from out of range input values, but this should get you started):

```
from functools import reduce

grid = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16],
        [17, 18, 19, 20]]

def get_diagonal(row, column, length):
    return [grid[row + i][column + i] for i in range(length)]

diag_list = get_diagonal(2, 1, 3)
diag_prod = reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, diag_list)

print(diag_list)
print(diag_prod)
# OUTPUT
# [10, 15, 20]
# 3000
```

If you are ultimately trying to combine into a single function, you could do something like this:

```
def get_diagonal_product(row, column, length):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, [grid[row + i][column + i] for i in range(length)])
```

Comment: Ah! Of course, I don't know why I hadn't thought to use an iterable inside of the indices of the list comprehension, especially considering that's what I was doing in my `for` loop! Many thanks. And, by the way, in my full code I did account for the diagonal potentially wanting to access bad indices, good to point that out though!